# When trying to display one table the other table with foreign key also shows up on the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq, lazy-loading

I am having two tables. taskList and taskdetails.
tasklist contains taskid and taskname.
taskid from tasklist is the foreign key to taskdetails.
I am displaying the tasklist table on a datagridview using this line of code mentioned here

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = db.taskLists.ToList();
```

when i run the code taskid and taskname gets displayed but along with that an empty column which contains taskdetails gets displayed.I tried disabling the lazy loading in the context db using this code

```
 this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Not sure whats the issue here.
I have uploaded two images with both my output for tasklist and taskdetail. Both are different windows form.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can shape the query using linq to contain just the properties which you need. Also as another option, you can add columns manually to datagridview. Also as another option, you can set `Visible` property of that column to `false` after setting data source.

Comment: You have a property TaskDetails in  your taskLists table, don't you ?

Comment: Another option is to decorate `taskLists` property with `[Browsable(false)]`

Comment: You can have a custom view model which contains properties which you want to display.

Comment: @RezaAghaei There is no way other than displaying it without the Specific properties required? I want to know why this  is happening and why lazy loading wont work.!

Comment: @Florian No , i dont have taskDetails property in taskList.

Comment: @Bharadwaj There is no way other than displaying it without the Specific properties required? I want to know why this is happening and why lazy loading wont work.!

Comment: Lazy loading is about loading data. Even if you don't load the data, the property is there. But when you you load data, the property fills with data. To show or not show the property, you should follow one one the solutions which are mentioned by me and Ivan.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the help! Using the same solution suggested by you'll. @RezaAghaei